# Unknown entity with Hibernate upgraded to 5.2.3 and above

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, gradle

As soon as I upgrade to Hibernate 5.2.3 or above, Gradle isn't able to find my Entity Classes anymore:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: data.model.User
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:768)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:744)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:749)
    at core.data.model.service.PersistenceService.lambda$create$0(PersistenceService.java:105)
    at core.data.model.service.PersistenceService.withTransaction(PersistenceService.java:156)
```

It doesn't happen with Hibernate 5.2.2 and below.

This didn't fix it: [what is gradle missing to map hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860669/what-is-gradle-missing-to-map-hibernate).

This is my User class:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends EntityBase {
    // some attributes
}
```

and my EntityBase class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.NONE)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public abstract class EntityBase {
    /**
     * The entity's UUID.
     */
    @Id
    @XmlAttribute
    private String uuid;

    public EntityBase() {
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

The tests have their own persistence.xml, it looks like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>data.model.User</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:exerciseHandlerTest;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"/>

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>

            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                      value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I also get this Exception when running the tests:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Difficulty is not mapped [select count(difficulty)
from Difficulty difficulty]
```

It is weird since this is happening only when running through Gradle, without it everything is *fine*.

**Update 1**

Apparently the problem isn't related to Gradle at all, because I just realized I am getting these Exceptions when running my Tests in IntellIJ:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at core.test.BaseTest.<init>(NablaTest.java:55)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/foobar]
    ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    ... 47 more
```

This makes me realize the Problem is that **Since Hibernate 5.2.3 using a second persistence.xml, just for the Unit Tests isn't working**

So I have a src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
and a src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml, but it keeps reading the persistence.xml from src/main/... starting with version 5.2.3 :(

**Update 2**

Okay, I know how to reproduce the problem, I just don't know why it's happening or how to fix it.

I have a multi-module-setup using the latest Gradle version. I have a core module with a build.gradle that contains the hibernate dependency:

```
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.3.Final"
```

And then there's my module where the unit tests are failing:

```
dependencies {
    // core functionalities
    compile project(":core")
    testCompile project(":core")

    testCompile project(":core").sourceSets.test.output
}
```

If I comment out the last line ("testCompile project(":core").sourceSets.test.output") it's working fine.

**Why is that?**

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your `User` class with its annotations and how you're registering these classes to be picked up by Hibernate; whether that is persistence.xml or some spring configuration, etc.

Comment: And I assume you're just creating a `User` instance, setting the values, and then calling `session.save( userInstance )` ?

Comment: I remember i had your problem before but i am not sure, anyway can you please tell me if this happen in your IDE or when u try to use command in cmd of windows or terminal in linux ? (i mean when u build ur project please use commands instead of your IDE) the last thing can u also try to use <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> instead of <class>data.model.User</class> and check what will happen

Comment: Naros: more or less, yes. Like I said: everything is working *fine* with previous versions of Hibernate.

@mibrahim.iti: Windows, happens using Gradle (gradlew check), doesn't happen when running tests using IntelliJ.

This might as well be a bug in Hibernate that occurs starting with Hibernate 5.2.3, but I can't figure out what change might have introduced it: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2.3/changelog.txt

Using exclude-unlisted-classes doesn't work either.

Comment: Any chance to define packages to scan? Like with @EntityScan(basePackageClasses=City.class) annotation or via session factory property ?

Comment: I am not using the Hibernate Session directly, I'm using the EntityManager. As far as I can see @EntityScan is a Spring Annotation? I am not using Spring.

Comment: As far as tests are concerned, you *need* a `<class>data.model.Difficulty</class>` for `Difficulty` to get picked up, even with `exclude-unlisted-classes` set to `false`. If you are also experiencing problems when running production code, double check the `META-INF/persistence.xml` ends up in the directory with compiled production classes.

Comment: Thanks, I do have a <class>...</class> for each of my Entites. Production is working fine.

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be `MappedSuperclass` annotation on the `EntityBase` instead of `Entity` annotation?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But that has nothing to do with my problem :)

Comment: So your module test's classes need some classes/ressources declared in the test part of Core, right ? Hence this line `(testCompile project(":core").sourceSets.test.output`

Comment: Yes, correct. That line is necessaryy.

Comment: can you provide me your code base?

Answer (score 0):

try to upload to Hibernate 5.2.9.Final, using maven for example, and follow this persistence example:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @Basic( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private UUID accountsPayableXrefId;

    @Lob
    @Basic( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @LazyGroup( "lobs" )
    private Blob image;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UUID getAccountsPayableXrefId() {
        return accountsPayableXrefId;
    }

    public void setAccountsPayableXrefId(UUID accountsPayableXrefId) {
        this.accountsPayableXrefId = accountsPayableXrefId;
    }

    public Blob getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Blob image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same type of situation, not the same error though. Test resources (class, conf files, etc...) should not be stored in the test part of `core` but in a standalone project.

My solution :

1. Create a separate `core-test` project
2. Insert into it (in `src/main`) the reusable code stored in the `src/test` part of `core`
3. In your modules, replace `testCompile project(":core").sourceSets.test.output` by `testCompile project(":core-test")`

It should resolve your issue.